# Select row matching ordered criteria when using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database of real estate properties. Some properties are listed more than once with different information. Here's some simplified data:

```
+--------------+---------+-----------------+------------------------+
| category     | price   | address         | remarks                |
+--------------+---------+-----------------+------------------------+
| Commercial   |  435000 | 1224 81ST AVE   | Great retail space!    |
| Multi Family |  435000 | 1224 81ST AVE   | Motivated seller!      |
| Residential  |  435000 | 1224 81ST AVE   | 0% down financing      |
| Residential  | 1095000 | 3290 NW BLUE LN | An exciting new…       |
| Land         |  150000 | 3878 COHO CIR   | Build your dream home… |
| Residential  |  540000 | 3918 COHO CIR   | Ultra-efficient home…  |
| Land         |  300000 | 3890 COHO CIR   | Light-filled condo…    |
| Multi Family |  300000 | 3890 COHO CIR   | Light-filled condo…    |
+--------------+---------+-----------------+------------------------+
```

Properties that are duplicated in the database can be identified by the `price` and `address` columns; in the example data above the first three rows and the last two rows are duplicated properties.

It's easy to use `GROUP BY price, address` to return only one row for each property. But I need to get the row for each group where `category` is `Residential`, then `Commercial`, then `Multi Family`, and finally `Land`. In other words, I want the row where `category=Residential` if that exists, otherwise where `category=Commercial`, etc.

The result should be:

```
+--------------+---------+-----------------+------------------------+
| category     | price   | address         | remarks                |
+--------------+---------+-----------------+------------------------+
| Residential  |  435000 | 1224 81ST AVE   | 0% down financing      |
| Residential  | 1095000 | 3290 NW BLUE LN | An exciting new…       |
| Land         |  150000 | 3878 COHO CIR   | Build your dream home… |
| Residential  |  540000 | 3918 COHO CIR   | Ultra-efficient home…  |
| Multi Family |  300000 | 3890 COHO CIR   | Light-filled condo…    |
+--------------+---------+-----------------+------------------------+
```

In the olden days of mysql < 5.7, I could use their nonstandard group by extension where a sort would apply before a row was selected by the GROUP BY, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM properties
GROUP BY price, address
ORDER BY FIELD(category, 'Residential', 'Commercial', 'Multi Family', 'Land')
```

This doesn't work anymore, because the sort is applied after the GROUP BY is applied, so the row that is selected is arbitrary.

There are many questions and answers addressing alternatives for sorted GROUP BY clause by using aggregate functions, but I can't find any discussion of my use case where a row is chosen based on custom sort function.

Is there a way to do this in pure MySQL? N.b.: I'm using MariaDB 10.1, which doesn't have `row_number()`.

Comment: Or upgrade to 10.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by price, address order by field(category, 'Residential', 'Commercial', 'Multi Family', 'Land')) as seqnum
      from properties p
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can also do this as:

```
select p.*
from products p
where field(category, 'Residential', 'Commercial', 'Multi Family', 'Land') =
          select field(p2.category, 'Residential', 'Commercial', 'Multi Family', 'Land')
          from products p2
          where p2.price = p.price and p2.address = p.address
          order by 1
          limit 1
         );
```

But . . . you really should upgrade to a more recent version of MariaDB.

Comment: I'm using MariaDB 10.1, which doesn't have that function: `ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION row_number does not exist`

Comment: MariaDB 10.1 was released in 2014.  It is time to update your software.

Comment: This was super helpful, thank you! Using a window function is perfect for this task. I'm going to ask the client if the hosting provider can update MariaDB.